# JQgrid Length of colNames and colModel error

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

OK. I have been going through many answers here but none of them worked. What i am trying to do is show my `JSON` response in `jqgrid`. But it shows this error:

**error:**

[image: JQGrid Error]

Here is the **code:**

```
var cols = ['VNo', 'Notes', 'Title'];
var colmodel = [
    { key: true, hidden: false, name: 'VNo', index: 'VNo' },
    { key: false, hidden: false, name: 'Notes', index: 'Notes' },
    { key: false, hidden: false, name: 'Title', index: 'Title' }
];
alert(colmodel.length);
$('#grid').jqGrid({
    url: "/Voucher/GetJournalVouchers",
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: "GET",
    colNames:cols,
    ColModel:colmodel,
    pager: jQuery('#pager'),
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
    height: '100%',
    viewreocrds: true,
    caption: 'Vouchers',
    emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
    jsonReader: {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "0"
    },
    autowidth: true,
    multiselect: false,
});
```

if I remove colNames it shows jqGrid but doesn't load any data. Here is `JSON` response I receive after removing colNames:
[image: Response]

Comment: Column name TransId in your data does not correspond to anything you declare in the grid

Comment: is it necessary to declare every column?

Comment: No clue, but that would be a thing to try

Comment: tried but same results

Comment: ColModel should be as  colModel

Comment: thanks a lot saved the hell out of me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ColModel:colmodel,` to`colModel:colmodel,` in grid definition. Its a spell mistake.